# Set values of groups in pandas conditionally python

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
duration, cost, channel 
  2       180      TV1
  1       200      TV2
  2       300      TV3
  1       nan      TV1
  2       nan      TV2
  2       nan      TV3
  2       nan      TV1
  1       40       TV2
  1       nan      TV3
```

Some of the cost values are nans, and to fill them I need to do the following:

- group by channel
- within a channel, sum the available cost and divide by the number of * occurrences (average)
- reassign values for all rows within that channel:

  - if duration = 1, cost = average * 1.5
  - if duration = 2, cost = average

Example:
TV2 channel, we have 3 entries, with one entry having null cost. So I need to do the following:

```
average = 200+40/3 = 80
if duration = 1, cost = 80 * 1.5 = 120

duration, cost, channel 
  2       180      TV1
  1       120      TV2
  2       300      TV3
  1       nan      TV1
  2       80       TV2
  2       nan      TV3
  2       nan      TV1
  1       120      TV2
  1       nan      TV3
```

I know i should do df.groupby('channel') and then apply function to each group.
The problem is that I need to modify not only null values, I need to modify all cost values within a group if 1 cost is null.

Any tips help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want something like:

```
def myfunc(group):

    # only modify cost if there are nan's
    if len(group) != group.cost.count():

        # set all cost values to the mean
        group['cost'] = group.cost.sum() / len(group)

        # multiply by 1.5 if the duration equals 1
        group['cost'][group.duration == 1] = group['cost'] * 1.5

    return group


df.groupby('channel').apply(myfunc)

   duration  cost channel
0         2    60     TV1
1         1   120     TV2
2         2   100     TV3
3         1    90     TV1
4         2    80     TV2
5         2   100     TV3
6         2    60     TV1
7         1   120     TV2
8         1   150     TV3
```

Comment: Thanks! But the cost column in df is not assigned the new values. And when I assign df.cost = df.groupby('channel').apply(myfunc), I'm getting an error.

Comment: In this case the apply value already returns the exact same df with only different cost values. So you can do: `df = df.groupby('channel').apply(myfunc)`. But if you insist on only modifying the cost column this would also work: `df['cost'] = df.groupby('channel').apply(myfunc)['cost']`. But i wouldnt use the latter since a change in the index might cause misalignment, even though it would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Pandas, the code should change to

```
def myfunc(group):
    # only modify cost if there are nan's
    if len(group) != group.cost.count():

        # set all cost values to the mean
        group['cost'] = group.cost.sum() / len(group)

        # multiply by 1.5 if the duration equals 1
        _ = group.set_value(group[group.duration == 1].index, 'cost', group['cost'] * 1.5)

    return group
```